# Angular JS / SQLite / Query

Tags: sql, sqlite, angularjs

I´m buidling a mobile App with Angular JS and SQLite for offline storage.

Does anybody have an idea how to structure the SQL statements?

I have my controllers and they call the factories, but is it a good idea to write the
statements into the factories? Http-request are not useful in this case. Is there a further "abstraction layer"?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
app.controller( 'loginController', function loginController($scope, loginFactory) {

  $scope.loginFactory = function() {
    return loginFactory.login($scope.firstnameLogin, $scope.passwordLogin);  
  };
});

app.factory('loginFactory', function() {
  return {
    login : function(firstnameLogin, passwordLogin) {

        // HERE THE SQL-STATEMENT? //

    }
  }
});
```

Edit: Added some code.

Comment: Is there code accompanying this question?

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually used javascript to connect to a SQLite database in the manner which you are asking, but it does seem that if you're using HTML5, you can connect to a data store in the browser and store  you data in a SQL like manner.

Adobe has a [walk through](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Store_data_in_the_HTML5_SQLite_database-19115.html) of how to connect and do your standard CRUD activities with this data store. After reading through the document, I would guess that you can then use the basics to build up an AngularJS factory to return the Create, Read, Update and Delete methods for you mobile application to use.

Good luck, hope this helps you come.

[Store data in the HTML5 SQLite database](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Store_data_in_the_HTML5_SQLite_database-19115.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris. To write the statements/connect to database is not really the problem... I would like to "swap/outsource" the sql-statements so that they are not within the factories...

Comment: DehMotth, can you share some info on how you were able to connect to SQLite DB from HTML5? AngularJS doesn't provide it out of the box from what I could gather, so are you using any other framework?